# I import sqlalchemy but i have this error sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask

I am new on flask, now am watching a course on youtube I do everything correctly but I have this error on one page:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: users.date_added
[SQL: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.name AS users_name, users.email AS users_email, users.date_added AS users_date_added 
FROM users ORDER BY users.date_added]
```

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

This is the code on sublime (route):

```py
app.route('/user/add', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add_user():
    name=None
    form=UserForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user=Users.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user is None:
            user=Users(name=form.name.data,email=form.email.data)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
        name=form.name.data
        form.name.data=''
        form.email.data=''
        flash('User added ')
    our_users=Users.query.order_by(Users.date_added)    
    return render_template('add_user.html' ,form=form,name=name,our_users=our_users)
```

**add_user.html** page code:

```
{% if name%}
    <h1>Hello {{name}}!!</h1>
{% else %}
    <h1>User list:</h1>
    <br>
    <form method="POST" >
            {{form.hidden_tag()}}
            {{form.name.label()}}
            {{form.name()}}
            <br>
            {{form.email.label()}}
            {{form.email()}}
            <br>
            <br>
            {{form.submit(class="btn btn-primary")}}
    </form> 
    {% for our_user in our_users %}
    
    {{our_user.id}} . {{our_user.name
    }} - {{our_user.email}}<br>
    
    {%endfor%}   
{%endif%}
```

Comment: Did y add `date_added` in the database? either manually or give a default current time?

Comment: yes i add it to db  'date_added=db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)'

Comment: are the default values getting inserted as expected? like can u check the database?

Comment: yes i can check it